# Extracting the header and the footer of html page

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

How to extract the header and the footer from [this page](http://superhub-project.eu/index.php) to insert it in another page?

I'm a bit confused because when I copy and paste the header div it never has the same structure and graphics in the new page? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Typically when you copy/paste the div you're getting the HTML, but not the CSS styling (unless the styling is in-line).

There is a Chrome extension called "[CSS + HTML](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pbgafccggboemhmcmnmglkgidbiigoeh)" that allows you to, in the developer console, generate a version of the div that has all CSS turned into in-line CSS, so that you can copy/paste a pretty accurate version.

(Caveats: I've had some issues with the extension, so I don't enable it except when I need it, and the HTML produced is a) awful, because it has lots of unnecessary inline CSS, and b) not always a precise match.  But it's pretty good.)

Comment: So I've already gotten at least one downvote; presumably the voter hates the idea of inline CSS.  So do I, but this specific situation (I need to reproduce part of a web page without pulling in all of the CSS files) does sometimes come up and this can be a really useful tool when it does.

Comment: I think you're right that someone was just bringing personal preferences (or a bad mood) to the forum. I upvoted your answer and the original question to counteract that person's unhelpful behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something.   The CSS, images, and links...  They are using relative links.  You would need to be sure to replace those links.

The images are linked relatively so unless you copy them local you will not have access to them.

You would also need the Style Sheets as they are linked relatively in the head.

Not that the links in some cases are to `.php` files.  Unless you know the php running in the background you are going to lose that functionality too.